# Create a circular/ring chart in Android

Tags: java, android, pie-chart, mpandroidchart

I would like to create a Circular/Ring chart on Android.

the result I want to achieve is the following:

[image]

Is there a library or any default way to create this?

Comment: Your "chart" doesn't look like a chart to me (what do the lines imply?) but you can probably model that after a pie chart. I suggest you look at the source code for an open source pie chart and implement your own I suppose. Quick google led me to this library: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart which has a pie chart.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Checkout this [library](https://github.com/txusballesteros/fit-chart).

It provides a comprehensive library to draw charts just like the way you want.

Comment: It seems just what I want. I'll try to use that library.